# Lumify demo server running on CentOS virtual machine Connection Refused

Tags: maven, centos, jetty

I have launched the Lumify-demo server on my Virtualbox hosted on Mac OSX. According to the documentation [here](https://github.com/lumifyio/lumify#lumify-demo-virtual-machine), as soon as vagrant is done provisioning the VM, I should be able to launch the webapp on my host machine's browser (after updating the hosts file). But the server seems to not be running . I receive `Lumify-demo refused to connect`
From all the rudimentary debugging I could do at my end, I think that the web server is not even installed on the VM.
Telnet from the host machine says connection refused
Tomcat7 and SERVER are unrecongnised when I do `service SERVER status`
`$JETTY_HOME` or `$JETTY_BASE` variables are not defined so I don't even know where to look for Jetty

Has someone else faced the same issue? Can someone confirm that I need to build the servers (*source has both Jetty and Tomcat so I figure I need to use both*) using maven (*which is not currently installed on CentOS VM*) and run/configure two servers (*both unknown territory*) all by myself?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I compared the `lumify-demo` with the `lumify-dev` virtual machine and it seemed like a lot was missing. So I provisioned the demo machine again only to find out that the provisioning was breaking in multiple places due to permission issues. 
Turned out to be a good exercise in gaining familiarity with Vagrant, and Jetty got installed